# Custom Date Format in Microsoft Word 2016

Tags: microsoft-word, date-time, microsoft-word-2016, date-format

I would like to be able to insert a date format in Microsoft Word that is not included in the list of existing formats. Specifically, I want this format:

> *DD* th day of *Month, YYYY*

Answer (score 5):

I’ll assume that you are talking about
one of the handful of date values that Word offers in fields. 
I’ll also assume that you are inserting fields through the ribbon / GUI,
and that you know how to do that. 
OK, when you’re in the “Field” setting window,
and you have selected the date you want
(“CreateDate”, (current) Date, “PrintDate” or “SaveDate”),
click on “Field Codes”. 
An “Advanced field properties” pane will appear,
with a “Field Codes:” text box
that’s prefilled with the name of the field you selected on the left
(which is just its display name in all-caps;
e.g., “CREATEDATE”, “DATE”, etc.)

Insert `\@ "d'th day of' MMMM, yyyy"` after that field name; e.g.,

[image: “Advanced field properties” pane]

Click “OK”.

Oh, I’m also assuming that you want the month spelled out. 
If you want only the three-letter abbreviation (e.g., “Dec”),
use `MMM` instead of `MMMM`.

Unfortunately, you’re asking the wrong question. 
Yes, this question was asked on the 5th day of December, 2017,
and the day before was the 4th. 
But the preceding three days were the 1st, 2nd and 3rd
(*not* the 1th, 2th and 3th). 
21st, 22nd, 23rd and 31st are also exceptions to the “th” rule
(but, perversely, 11th, 12th and 13th are not). 
This sequence of fields
will produce the correct ordinal numbers for English:

```
(1)     { set the_date { date } }
(2)     { Set day { the_date \@ “d” } }
(3)     { Set dec { = int(day / 10) } }
(4)     { Set d10 { =mod(day,10) } }
(5)     { Set suffix { If dec = 1 “th” { If d10 = 1 “st” { If d10 = 2 “nd” { If d10 = 3 “rd” “th” } } } } }
(6)     { Set format { Quote “d'” { suffix } “ day of' MMMM, yyyy” } }
(7)     { The_Date \@ { format } }
```

Line numbers are just for illustration / exposition purposes
and are not part of the document / code. 
This seems to be case-insensitive
(except in the date format, where `m` is minutes and `M` is month). 
And "straight quotes" ([image: straight quotes])
and “curly quotes” ([image: curly quotes]) seem to be interchangeable.

1. Assign the date to a variable (technically, a “bookmark”)
   called `the_date`. 
   Change the last word to `createdate`, `printdate`, or `savedate`
   if that’s what you want.
2. Get the day number of `the_date` (e.g., “Dec 5” → 5)
   and assign it to the variable `day`.
3. Get the ten’s digit of `day` (e.g., 5 → 0, 17 → 1, 23 → 2)
   and assign it to the variable `dec`.
4. Get the one’s digit of `day` (e.g., 5 → 5, 17 → 7, 23 → 3)
   and assign it to the variable `d10`.
5. Determine the appropriate ordinal suffix for `day`. 
   If `dec` is 1, then `day` is between 10 and 19, and the suffix is “th”. 
   Otherwise, if `d10` is 1, 2, or 3,
   the suffix is “st”, “nd”, or “rd”, respectively. 
   For all other values, the suffix is “th”. 
   Then assign it to the variable `suffix`.
6. Build a format string
   like the one I used in the first part of the answer. 
   Concatenate `d'`, the suffix (`suffix`) from the previous step,
   and  `day of' MMMM, yyyy`. 
   This uses a trick (using the `quote` field)
   that I learned at [the Microsoft Community](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word-mso_winother-mso_2013_release/concatenate-form-fields-in-word-2013/e76bbec9-8adf-4241-bd79-f484f721ee52?auth=1);
   I don’t fully understand it.
7. This is basically a repetition of the first part of the answer,
   but displaying `the_date` according to the format `format`.

To use this, copy the following and paste it into your Word document:

```
set the_date date
Set day the_date \@ "d"
Set dec = int(day / 10)
Set d10 =mod(day,10)
Set suffix If dec = 1 “th” If d10 = 1 “st” If d10 = 2 “nd” If d10 = 3 “rd” “th”
Set format Quote “d'” suffix “ day of' MMMM, yyyy”
The_Date \@ format
```

(In the above, the capitalization and spacing
(e.g., `day / 10` vs. `day,10`) are arbitrary / random
(except in the `format` string).)

1. On the first line.

- Select `date` (or `createdate`, or whichever one you use)
  and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd>. 
  It will change to `{ date }`
  and may have a gray background. 
  This same transformation will occur
  every time you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd>,
  ultimately looking like the first code block (way above). 
  Do not type any curly braces!
- Next, select the entire line and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd>.

2. On the second line.

- Select `the_date \@ “d”` and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd>.
- Then select the entire line and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd>.

3. On the third line.

- Select `= int(day / 10)` and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd>.
- Then select the entire line and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd>.

4. On the fourth line.

- Select `=mod(day,10)` and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd>.
- Then select the entire line and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd>.

5. On the fifth line.

- Select `If d10 = 3 “rd” “th”` (at the end of the line)
  and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd>.
- Then select `If d10 = 2 “nd” { If d10 = 3 “rd” “th” }`
  and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd>.
- Then select `If d10 = 1 “st” { If d10 = 2 “nd” { If d10 = 3 “rd” “th” } }`
  and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd>.
- Then select `If dec = 1 “th” { If d10 = 1 “st” { If d10 = 2 “nd” { If d10 = 3 “rd” “th” } } }`
  and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd>.
- Then select the entire line and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd>.

6. On the sixth line.

- Select `suffix` and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd>.
- Then select `Quote “d'” { suffix } “ day of' MMMM, yyyy”`
  (i.e., from `Quote` to the end of the line)
  and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd>.
- Then select the entire line and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd>.

7. On the seventh line.

- Select `format` and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd>.
- Then select the entire line and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd>.

Note that line 7 is the only one that actually produces any text;
the first six are setup
and can be moved somewhere like the beginning of the document. 
You might want to delete the paragraph breaks between the fields
to avoid having them take up a bunch of vertical space. 
Then select all the fields (or the entire document,
e.g., with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>)
and press <kbd>F9</kbd> (***not*** <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd>). 
The fields (except for the last one) might all disappear. 
If so, this is normal, and you’re done. 
If they don’t disappear, press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd> 
(again, ***not*** <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd>), and that should do it.

---

P.S. I checked this on Word 2013, and that’s what the screenshot is from.

Comment: It's a real shame that many date formatting systems can't handle this basic UK requirement "out of the box" to show dates as 2th Oct 2023.